# Magento 2 Certification Exam Question?

Tags: certification

I want to give Magento 2 Certification exam. I have some question regarding this exam. can any buddy give my questin's answer?

1) Can I reschedule my examination date, time and center all of this?

> I have found this in **about the exam**:- 
>   Based on Magento Open Source (2.2) and Magento Commerce (2.2), **but
>   applicable to those using any version of Magento 2.**

2) Can the exams question is related to Magento version 2.2.X? Or 2.2.X and above? Currently, Magento latest version is 2.3.0. it is included in this exam or not?

Comment: As far as I saw on slack group of certification.  Around June 2019 Magento will update questions with latest version 2.3.

Comment: you can get the details in this link https://tagvibe.com/adobe-commerce-developer-expert-certification-exam-objectives-and-scope/

Answer (score 3):

1. You can re-schedule or cancel your exam up to 72 hours prior to your scheduled onsite exam, or 24 hours prior to your scheduled online exam at no charge. Exam rescheduling or cancellation that occurs with less notice than indicated above, will be subject to a change fee of $50.
2. Currently, all exams are based on Magento version 2.2.x. At the time of answering, Magento 2.3 is not included in any of the certification tests.

Answer (score 2):

**Latest study guide certifications:updated [21 August 2020]**:

- **[AD0-E700]:** *Adobe Certified Expert Magento Commerce Business Practitioner*  [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/87jLctNB6KxM0/)
- **[AD0-E701]:** *Adobe Certified Expert-Magento Commerce Front-End Developer* [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/lJWBfPhvp5npA/)
- **[AD0-E702]:** *Adobe Certified Professional—Magento Commerce Developer*  [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/saM506xrYKi0p/)
- **[AD0-E703]:** *Adobe Certified Expert - Magento Commerce Developer* [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/OwpmK2JcACwhl/)
- **[AD0-E704]:** *Adobe Certified Master Magento Commerce Architect* [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/PTidDHsT5JgyB/)
- **[AD0-E705]:** *Adobe Certified Expert-Magento Commerce JavaScript Developer*  [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/ZDus3If2u1rQf/)
- **[AD0-E706]:** *Adobe Certified Expert-Magento Commerce Cloud Developer* [available since June 2018] [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/GrkbPktpWMkkb/)
- **[Adobe AD0-E707]** Adobe Certified Expert Magento Commerce Order Management Developer [Details](https://spark.adobe.com/page/K2Wjl6Na3BY0h/)

Answer (score 1):

As of now magento 2.3.0 questions not included in exams.

yes you can reschedule your exam before 72 hrs of exam(you need to pay some extra charges for that) .

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you can reschedule date,time,center but they have some condition
   like you have to change it 72 hours before exam so that they
   can process your request.

   2. Right Now magento exam questions are put up from 2.2.X not above but in future question can come from magento 2.3

You can find out magento exam information from [here](https://u.magento.com/certification).

Answer (score 1):

ABOUT THE EXAM
60 Multiple Choice items
90 minutes to complete the exam
A score of 68% or higher is needed to pass the Magento 2 Certified Associate Developer exam
Based on Magento Open Source (2.3) and Magento Commerce (2.3), but applicable to those using any version of Magento 2.

[magento-2-certified-associate-developer-exam](https://u.magento.com/magento-2-certified-associate-developer-exam#.XJ4Kgp9fjeQ)